# Will a cloudlifter get rid of noise for (RE20, Focusrite solo) combo for talking?

Tags: microphone, interface

Currently, I own an RE20 along with a focusrite solo interface.

I find that recordings of me speaking is quite noisy.

Two questions:

1. What's the purpose of a cloudlifter? (is it solely to increase the input)
2. Does a cloudlifter also get rid of the noise?

Comment: Suggest you ask these as two separate questions.

Comment: Insofar as it's a dynamic microphone -- how high do you have the gain turned up? If you turned it up high enough that you're getting noise from the preamps, then a Cloudlifter may well help.